# Google prettify in an offline / localhost application requesting external files

Tags: javascript, css, svn, google-code-prettify

The google prettify is working great for me. I have built an application with a Twitter bootstrap front-end and the google prettify syntax highlighting. But the application is also used for working offline e.g. localhost, so I included the prettify.js and prettify.css.

Now when I go offline and work in the application, it will start looking for online code through the local prettify.js version:

- `https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/lang-"+encodeURIComponent(D[m])+".js`
- `https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/skins/"+encodeURIComponent(N[m])+".css`
- `https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/prettify.css`

It is working fine offline, but why is it requesting the external js and css files and how can I remove this from the minified prettify.js? I don't need it and it is slowing down the application.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Specifically, what `<script>` and `<link>` elements does it have, and what does it run on-load?

Comment: Hi Mike, I need to work offline, but in the prettify.js file it is calling externally: 
`e.src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/lang-"+encodeURIComponent(D[m])+".js";` See the Google project here: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GettingStarted](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted#Serving_your_own_JS_&_CSS) wiki page explains:

> ## Serving your own JS & CSS
>
> You can download the scripts and styles and serve them yourself. Make sure to include both the script and a stylesheet:
>
> ```
> <link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
> <script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: That is what I am doing Mike, but look inside the prettify.js and you will find that it is requesting more files from googlecode. I would like to know how I can use all of it and still keep it working.

Comment: @Theo, If you load `prettify.js` instead of `runprettify.js` then it won't load those other files.  Are you sure you didn't save `runprettify.js` as `prettify.js` by mistake?